# How do I add personality and emotion to voice using pytssx3?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Take your words back! Stackoverflow is the best out there. HANDS DOWN!")
engine.runAndWait()
```

I can change the rate, choose the voice between male or female but its pretty robotic.

I am using this solution for my text to voice needs but I want the voice to have a personality.
Not having a robotic voice in certain situations helps. I would like to add emotion to it.

Is there any way it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

pytts3x doesn't support emotion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31344764)

Comment: @theTinMan It seems to answer the question to me. Telling someone something is not possible is also an answer.

Comment: Is there any other library out there that can or does support this function?
I can understand that it requires a look ahead function that needs the ability to look up.

Comment: In Python, no, I don't think so. The main modules (pyttsx3 and gtts) do not have the ability to do so. You could look into the DeepLearning TTS modules on PyPi, but I haven't been able to find any.